# DataRowComparer returns false

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

I want to check if the values of 2 DataRows are the same. The rows are from 2  different DataTables, but table 2 is cloned from table 1 so the structures are the same.

The DataRowComparer returns false, but if I check the values in a loop the are all "Equal". I can obviously use the loop, but why does the DataRowComparer not work? Reading MSDN the DataRowComparer is a column-by-column, value-based comparison og two DataRow objects.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Mark

```
Dim blnEqualOriginal As Boolean = DataRowComparer.Equals(drTempOriginal, drTemp)

    For z = 0 To dtTempOriginal.Columns.Count - 1
        If drTempOriginal(z).ToString = drTemp(z).ToString Then
             Debug.WriteLine("Equal")
        Else
             Debug.WriteLine("Not equal")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: try `DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(drTempOriginal, drTemp)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your suggestion works!